# Why are .local and .arpa DNS queries showing up outside my network on OpenDNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, internal-dns

We have a Windows office network with a local Actice Directory/DNS domain server.  The server is set up with OpenDNS's servers as forwarders (see [screenshot](http://postimage.org/image/5vtis4vpz/)).  However, when I look at [my OpenDNS query statistics](http://postimage.org/image/ywxv1jg5z/), I notice that the 3rd most popular query is *.in-addr-arpa, and the 12th is *.local which is from our local domain.

Should I, or how can I prevent these local queries from going beyond my local network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent internal queries from being forwarded to the outside DNS server, your internal DNS server needs to be authoritative for the internal zones, not just the subdomains of them that you're using.

However, you seem to have a misconception here; `in-addr.arpa` is ***not*** internal to your network; it is used for all IPv4 reverse name lookups for every address on the internet.  Do not make your internal server think it's authoritative for all of `in-addr.arpa`.

Comment: So I need to create a new forward lookup zone for just "local"? rather than just mysubdomain.local?  Will that be enough to make it authoritative?

Comment: Yes, it will.  The queries making it out of your network are outside of `mysubdomain.local`, correct?

Comment: I can't tell exactly what "*.local" queries are making it beyond my network.  All I know is what is shown in my OpenDNS statistics screenshot linked in my original question, which shows "*.local".  I guess I will need to turn on debug logging?

Comment: Turned on debug logging but still can't find any .local dns queries that are not prepended by one of my subdomains.

Comment: So are queries for a subdomain your server's authoritative for making it out to OpenDNS?

Comment: I'm not sure.  My question stems from my OpenDNS stats (shown in screenshot in original question) that shows that the 12th most queried zone is \*.local.  There's no subdomain listed in those stats, just the asterisk dot local.  Is there a way to log (or filter) only the queries that my server is sending on to my forwarders?